# When floating left and right, which DIV is located first?

Tags: html, css

Does it matter which `<div>` is located first in the HTML?  If so, why?

```
.float-left{float:left;}
.float-right{float:right;}

<div>
  <div class="float-left">Left</div>
  <div class="float-right">Right</div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="float-right">Right</div>
  <div class="float-left">Left</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean located first? In the dom or how it is displayed?

Comment: @dwreck08  How the HTML is written.  EDIT.  I guess this is the same as the DOM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplifying, floats behave like this <sub><sup>(see [the precise rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#float-rules))</sup></sub>:

- Floats are placed as high as possible (but not higher than line boxes with content generated earlier in the source document).
- Left-floats are placed as far to the left as possible, without overlapping previous floats in document order.
- Right-floats are placed as far to the right as possible, without overlapping previous floats in document order.

Therefore, if you have a left-float and a right-float, and both fit in the same line, document order does not matter.

Otherwise, floats that appear first in document order will be displayed  higher.

```css
div {
  margin: 30px 0;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  counter-reset: float;
}
.wide { width: 75%; }
.left{ float: left; background: #ff0; }
.right{ float: right; background: #0ff; }
span:before { content: counter(float) ". ";  counter-increment: float; }
```

```html
<div><span class="left">Left</span><span class="right">Right</span></div>
<div><span class="right">Right</span><span class="left">Left</span></div>
<div><span class="left wide">Left</span><span class="right wide">Right</span></div>
<div><span class="right wide">Right</span><span class="left wide">Left</span></div>
```

Comment: I recall reading way back when that the `right` div should be located first, but I don't recall why or whether this advise was even correct.

Comment: @user1032531 Maybe it was because if you want to place a right-floated element at the right of a non-floating block, the floated element must be before the block, not after.

Comment: I think that was the situation.  Why must it be that way?  Thanks

Comment: @user1032531 Because if floats could be positioned as high as previous non-floating elements, how you would decide the upper limit?

Answer (score 1):

The renderer works it way down the page, sequentially applying the styles to the page.

This means the first `div` gets the styles applied to it first, the second gets its styles applied second and so on:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p41wr6gp/)

The [MDN Float page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) contains more detailed information.

Another interesting thing to be aware of is how [stacking order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_and_float) is also affected.

Comment: If the first `div` gets the style applied first, does this have any implications.   I read something a while ago that the right div should be located first, but I don't recall why or whether this advise was even correct.

Comment: It does have implications, especially if you use absolute positioning (which can affect stacking order). In general, there's no set rule to apply rules to the right `div` first, it's all dependent on the design.